# ListViewのsetListAdapterがエラーになる。

Tags: android

`ActionBarActivity`内の`ListView`に関して質問です。dummyデータを表示させたいのですが以下のコードの一番下

> setListAdapter(this, ExampleItems);

でエラーが発生してしまいます。
エラー内容は、`cannot resolve method ’setListAdapter’`
実は、`ListFragment`で利用していたものを参考にしたのですが、`ActionbarActivity`では、違うようで躓いてしまっております。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example1);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    // TODO: Delete dummy data
    ExampleItems = new ArrayList<ExampleElement>();

    int maxLength = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
        ExampleElement item = new ExampleElement();
        item.setAccountName("User Name");
        item.setImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ExampleItems.add(item);
    }

    setListAdapter(this, ExampleItems);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActionBarActivity`は`ListActivity`ではないので、`setListAdapter()`メソッドはありません。。。

Comment: 理解しました。ありがとうございます。